# Custom error metrics in Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a (Python) Lambda function that I'm calling via AWS API Gateway (not using "Lambda Proxy integration").

The Lambda accepts a JSON payload, and if all goes well returns a JSON response.

In terms of monitoring the Lambda, I can see the following in CloudWatch:

- invocations
- duration
- throttles
- errors

The Lambda can fail in a number of ways, and in each of these cases a JSON error object is returned as the response.

I would like to add the ability to view metrics of these error conditions in CloudWatch, but reading the documentation on Cloudwatch alerts and alarms, it is not clear to me how to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `CloudWatchMetricRecorder` to record custom metrics in lambda.